# Zend Framework 2 checked checkbox if input value = 1

Tags: php, checkbox, zend-framework2

I'm doing a new module based on http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/ and I have got one problem. How to make the checkbox checked if value = 1?

**view/index.phtml**

```
<?php

$title = 'Newsletter';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>

<h1>Newsletter</h1>
<p>Select users who are to receive the newsletter.</p>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td width="80%"><strong>User_id</strong></td>
        <td width="10%" align="center"><strong>Yes/No</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($newsletters as $newsletter) : ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($newsletter->user_id); ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($newsletter->wantNewsletter); ?> <input type="checkbox" name="wantNewsletter" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($newsletter->wantNewsletter); ?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><button>Zapisz</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about checking the checkbox. It will be done automatically for you, but in order to make it work you have to tweak it first.

First of all, you need to define the checkbox in your form:

```
final class SomeForm extends Form
{

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        .....

        // Add the checkbox here
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'wantNewsletter',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
        ));
```

Then in template, you can simply render it:

```
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('wantNewsletter'));
```

And if the attribute `wantNewsletter` has a value which is `1`, then the checkbox will be checked automatically.

Another solution you have, which is actually a work-around for this task, can be done simply by rendering a property when a value is `1`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="wantNewsletter" value="<?php echo $newsletter->wantNewsletter); ?>" <?php echo $newsletter->wantNewsletter ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
```

Use the first solution whenever possible as its more accurate and more framework-compliant.